# Windows Server running on SME small clusters setup, not "consumer-grade device", why is this off topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [How to make Ipv6 Prefix delegation with Windows Server 2022 acting as a router?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80422/how-to-make-ipv6-prefix-delegation-with-windows-server-2022-acting-as-a-router)

The question is for Windows Server running on SME small clusters setup, not "consumer-grade device". I don't understand the decision. Asking for clarification would be nice, instead of the heavy-handed moderation.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about servers are explicitly off-topic for [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). A Windows server is not an enterprise-grade router that would be on-topic.

You can ask your question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for a home network, or on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for a business network. Both sites handle networking on Windows devices.

Comment: The definition of enterprise-grade is clearly very arbitrary. While I won't accept any more request to do this Windows Server as router task (there are better ones over there)., Windows Routing and Remote Access Service (RRAS) is pretty much aimed and actually used by Enterprise. 

Luckily, I found my answer at the other forum, so I won't bother arguing further. It is a shame this stack exchange prioritized overzealous curation over actually being an actual knowledge exchange platform. Real example: I can no longer answer my own question.

Comment: RRAS and other server stuff is handled on [sf]. Dedicated, enterprise-grade network hardware (on-topic here) will be faster and scale. [networkengineering.se] was split off from [sf] to deal with network engineering separate from hosts/servers.

Comment: General rule: The question to ask oneself before submitting here isn't "Is this *relevant* to Network Engineering?"; rather, it is "Is this ***ir**relevant* to every site other than Network Engineering?".